# Auto-complete search box in python using ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Here is my code:

## model.py

`class Bookmark(models.Model):`

> `url = models.URLField()`
>       `title = models.CharField('title', max_length=255)`
>       `description = models.TextField('description', blank=True)`
>       `is_public = models.BooleanField('public', default=True)`
>       `date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created')`
>       `date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated')`
>       `owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='owner',
>           related_name='bookmarks')`
>       `tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)`
>       `views = models.IntegerField(default=0)`
>       `objects = models.Manager()`
>       `public = PublicBookmarkManager()`

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'bookmark'
    verbose_name_plural = 'bookmarks'
    ordering = ['-date_created']

def __str__(self):
    return '%s (%s)' % (self.title, self.url)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.date_created = now()
    self.date_updated = now()
    super(Bookmark, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`
```

## views.py

`def bookmark_search(request):`

> `query_string = ''`
>       `found_entries = None`
>       `if ('q' in request.GET) and request.GET['q'].strip():`

```
    query_string = request.GET['q']

    entry_query = get_query(query_string, ['id', 'url', 'title'])

    found_entries = Bookmark.objects.filter(entry_query).order_by('-date_created')
context = { 'query_string': query_string, 'found_entries': found_entries }
return render(request,'marcador/bookmark_search.html',context)`
```

## urls.py

urlpatterns = [

> `url(r'^search/?$', 'marcador.views.bookmark_search',
>           name='marcador_bookmark_search'),`
>   ]

## bookmark_search.html

`{% block search %}`
`{% url "marcador_bookmark_search" as action_url %}`
`<form class="navbar-form navbar-right search" role="form" method="get" action="{{ action_url }}" accept-charset="utf-8">`

> `<div class="form-group">`
>       `<label for="id_q"></label>`
>       `<input type="text" id="id_q" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control" name="q">`
>       `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="GO"/>`
>       `</div>`
>   `</form>`
>   `{% endblock %}`

I have this code and I am do searching submitting the button of search box.
but now I want to directly display database data when I click on search box and write some latter using Ajax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery-autocomplete-light:

1. Get [jquery-autocomplete-light's autocomplete.js](https://github.com/yourlabs/jquery-autocomplete-light/blob/master/src/autocomplete.js), ensure it's loaded in the HTML page, see [django on staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/) if you're not fluent with that already, if you're still confused, try [surviving staticfiles howto](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/30382323418/surviving-djangocontribstaticfiles-or-how-to)
2. Create a view for inside the autocomplete box, [example](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/stable-2.x.x/navigation.html#a-simple-view)
3. Configure autocomplete.js with a script tag in your HTML page, [example](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/stable-2.x.x/navigation.html#a-basic-autocomplete-configuration)

That's used in [ilstravaillentpourvous.fr](http://ilstravaillentpourvous.fr) in the top right search box, because this website is opensource, you can also [inspect it](https://github.com/SocieteCitoyenne/IlsTravaillentPourVous/): [autocomplete.js configuration](https://github.com/SocieteCitoyenne/IlsTravaillentPourVous/blob/master/templates/base.html#L83-L88), [autocomplete view](https://github.com/SocieteCitoyenne/IlsTravaillentPourVous/blob/master/ilstravaillentpourvous/views.py#L17-L29), [autocomplete template](https://github.com/SocieteCitoyenne/IlsTravaillentPourVous/blob/master/templates/autocomplete.html), [autocomplete url](https://github.com/SocieteCitoyenne/IlsTravaillentPourVous/blob/master/ilstravaillentpourvous/urls.py#L9-L10).

Comment: I don't know because I'm beginner in django,   can we do that in front-end in my site view search box auto-complete using this package

Comment: Yes, you'll make it, just try harder ;)